# Request for new tag for Apache MQ

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Can someone please create a tag for Apache MQ - the closest I can find at present is apache.

Answer (score 1):

Done

Actually, on further investigation, it looks like the correct tag for Apache MQ is [activemq](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/activemq), so I will probably synonym [apache-mq](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apache-mq) to [activemq](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/activemq) unless there's a good reason not to?

Comment: Really should be [apache-activemq], though [activemq] is acceptable.